# Trouble with local Notifications

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, alarm, android-alarms

Recently I just transferred all my code from a Xamarin.Forms Project which had local notifications representing alarms to a Android project in Android studio. The flow of scheduling this alarm is as follows and worked just fine in the Xamarin project but won't fire in the Android project:

**Create Alarm Here using a Controller class**

```
//Get the time in string format with the meridian
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String timeString = timeFormatter.format(new Date(oneTimeAlarm.getTime()));
    SimpleDateFormat meridianFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("a");
    String meridianString = meridianFormatter.format(new Date(oneTimeAlarm.getTime()));

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

    //Provide Settings
    intent.putExtra("Vibrate", alarm.getVibrateOn());
    intent.putExtra("Id", alarm.getId());
    intent.putExtra("Snooze", alarm.getSnoozeLength());
    intent.putExtra("Time",timeString);
    intent.putExtra("Meridian",meridianString);
    intent.putExtra("Uri", alarm.getRingtoneURI());

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTime(),pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm Scheduled!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The Controller successfully schedules the alarm with the proper settings and uses the AlarmManager to set the proper trigger time.

**AlarmerReceiver which is a custom BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

    //Get values for alarm
    Boolean vibrate = intent.getBooleanExtra("Vibrate",false);
    String ringtoneURI = intent.getStringExtra("Uri");
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("Id",0);
    int snoozeLength = intent.getIntExtra("Snooze",5);
    String displayTime = intent.getStringExtra("Time");
    String displayMeridian = intent.getStringExtra("Meridian");

    //If this is an update cancel the original
    Intent cancel = new Intent("Dismiss");
    PendingIntent cancelPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,id,cancel,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    //Pass parameters to AlarmActivity so it can have same settings for snooze refire.
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmActivity.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("SNOOZE",snoozeLength);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("VIBRATE",vibrate);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("URI",ringtoneURI);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("ID",id);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("TIME",displayTime);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("MERIDIAN",displayMeridian);

    PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    //Build Notification
    builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp)
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingAlarmIntent,true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingAlarmIntent)
            .setContentTitle("NapChat Alarm")
            .setContentText("Open Alarm")
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
   .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
 .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);


 NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(id,builder.build());
```

**Activity shown when alarm fires**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Window window = this.getWindow();

    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    //window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);


    initialize();
...
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alarmsproject.alarmsprojectandroid">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" />

    <activity android:name=".Activities.OptionsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.AlarmActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.CreateAlarmActivity"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Can anyone discern where I am going wrong here and why it won't fire. I am targeting API level 25 to avoid using the NotificationsChannel that came out for API 26. Why won't my notifications show? Especially since the exact code worked months before.

Comment: Paste your Manifest as well

Comment: Alarms have been changes in such a way that they can be delayed and this is due to bundling. Also did you verify that your alarm is set appropriately by looking at the time you are setting it to at via logs?

Comment: Yes I make sure to convert the time to utc milliseconds when setting it with the alarm manager since the alarm objects time is saved as such and used in the setExact() method

Comment: Have you tried it with the direct callback overload? Does it work?

Comment: I understand there are two independent steps (triggering an alarm, then showing a notification) and the first one doesn't work. If so, `adb shell dumpsys alarm` may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the receiver in the manifest.

```
<application ...>
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver> 
</application>
```

You probably had this decorator in your Xamarin project and removed it when you transferred it? Which might explain how it worked in Xamarin.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
```

Comment: That definitely was something I was missing but the notification still did not fire. I have just seen that in Settings > Apps & Notifications > MyApp that the Permissions section says "no permissions requested". Even though notifications is on for this app could that possibly be blocking them from showing up? Also I just tried to schedule an alarm using the built in Clock app on the Emulator and it posted a Toast to indicate it was trying to schedule a notification without the use of a channel. Which seems strange since wouldn't the default system be using the proper API?